# Mac Lion no java webapplets

Tags: mac, osx-lion, java, java-applet

I have Lion MacOS X, since my computer was sent to apple tech support I can't execute ANY java webapplet (however java locally works fine), I read that I must enable java from Java Preferences, however this has not worked, I've been enabling and disabling java for 3 days (even I restarted).

What can I do?

Comment: Does it apply to all browsers? Or have you checked if Java is enabled in the preferences of the browsers you use?

Comment: It affects all browsers, I'm taking about the"java preferences" i read that i should enable java in this preferences searching this in spotlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like a reinstall of Lion did all the work, no clean install is need though :), thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

From MacUpdate:

> Java for OS X Lion delivers improved security, reliability, and
>   compatibility by updating Java SE 6 to 1.6.0_33.
>
> This update configures the Java plug-in to deactivate when no applets
>   are run for an extended period of time. If the prior update named
>   "Java for OS X 2012-003" was not installed, this update will disable
>   the Java web plug-in immediately. Java applets may be re-enabled by
>   clicking the region labeled "Inactive plug-in" on a web page.
>
> Please quit any web browsers and Java applications before installing
>   this update.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that java doesnt ask when to be enabled, however i enabled it through java preferences